# Finding chromium

Tags: synthesis, metal, metallurgy

If I were to go back in time to pre-industrial Earth, and I wanted to make stainless steel, would there be a way to find chromium and/or chromite? It doesn't matter what chemical form the chromium takes or what its purity is, as long as there is sufficient chromium.

Comment: See https://mineralseducationcoalition.org/minerals-database/chromium/

Comment: What are looking for ? A chromium mineral that does contain chromium without the scientist knowing it ?

Comment: Anything like post-apocalypse scenario when skills and knowledge is lost and remnants of people try to restart civilizationalmost from the scratch? Or just some reconstruction of medieval/early industrial procedures and findings?

Comment: @Poutnik Yes, a post-apocalypse scenario fits what I'm asking pretty well.

Comment: @Maurice In my hypothetical, there would be very few, if any, people that know what chromium is. In that scenario, how would you find it? I know my hypothetical is a little weird for this forum. I am writing a book, and doing research for it. Again, apologies if it doesn't fit the forum.

Comment: If they do not know what chromium is, why to search for it?

Comment: @Poutnik Because the person searching for it knows what it is, and wants to use it to make stainless steel.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not see what you are looking for. Are you looking for a man who knows what chromium is without knowing chromium ?

Comment: I would say making useable steel would be more impressive than finding chrome ore.

Comment: Are you looking for chemical tests for chromium? What kind of equipment or tests would be available or possible?

Comment: If the technology has been lost, meteoritic iron often has enough nickel and other elements to make it highly rust resistant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteoric_iron, https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/before-iron-age-most-iron-came-from-space-meteorite-egyptian-bronze

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for earth sciences SE, depending on what you are focusing on....

Comment: Check out a show called "Dr. Stone". It will be perfect for you.

Answer (score 3):

In some river systems chromite is a relatively common mineral. One could extract it in a similar manner to gold: panning, sluicing, etc. In certain rivers and creeks draining the right geology one could feasibly get anywhere between 10-100+ grams a day panning. The hard part would be reducing it and using it to make steel.

Native chromium samples have been found in strong natural reducing environments, notably kimberlite pipes, but they (both kimberlite pipes and native chromium) are very rare, while chromite is much more widespread.